# How to get Safari's "new page" effect?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, mobile-safari

how can I integrate Safari's zoom out effect you see when opening a new page be used in my own app?

[image]

I want to present the user **different sheets of paper**. Normally you see one paper but with the ability to "zoom out" so that you can **choose another sheet**.
So far I've seen it integrated in "Buy Me a Pie!".
Thanks!